# How do i enable public comments on a blog page in Kademi

Tags: comments, blogs, kademi

I have a small landing page site hosted in the Kademi platform, with pages managed using the blogs app. I need to allow public users (ie not logged in) to post comments on that page, and to display comments.

But currently its disallowing posts from anonymous users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a checkbox in setting panel of "Forums, topics and questions" app which allows anonymous users can comment on a blog. You can find this app in **Application** list of your instance (by click **Application** menu item under **Website Manager** in left menu) or in **Apps** tab in your website configuration screen.

Cheers,
Duc